# REACT NATIVE / my child component don't re-render despite props change

Tags: react-native, react-props, use-effect, use-state, react-state

I'm facing an issue on the code below (sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-rubin-9ghc5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark ), the props change but doesn't refresh the component accordingly.

I would like to be able to keep track of different votes / options within a state in the parent node, hence i'm using an array where the index is the index of my option and the value the number of votes.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";

import "./styles.css";

const myList = [
  {
    cid: 0,
    cTx: "Paris"
  },
  {
    cid: 1,
    cTx: "Lyon"
  },
  {
    cid: 2,
    cTx: "Marseille"
  },
  {
    cid: 3,
    cTx: "Valence"
  },
  {
    cid: 4,
    cTx: "Bordeaux"
  }
];

interface mTprop {
  myItemId: number;
  myItemTxt: string;
  myItemSt: number[];
  myItemClck: () => void;
}

const MyItem = (props: mTprop) => {
  const onBtPress = () => {
    props.myItemClck();
    console.log(props.myItemSt);
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row"
      }}
    >
      <h3>{props.myItemTxt}</h3>
      <Button onPress={onBtPress} title="Learn More" />
      <h3>{props.myItemSt[props.myItemId]}</h3>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOpt, setSelectedOpts] = useState(new Array(0));

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedOpts(new Array(myList.length).fill(0));
  }, []);

  const updateOptions = (ix: number) => {
    ++selectedOpt[ix];
    setSelectedOpts(selectedOpt);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {myList.map((itm, ix) => {
        return (
          <MyItem
            key={ix}
            myItemId={ix}
            myItemTxt={itm.cTx}
            myItemSt={selectedOpt}
            myItemClck={() => updateOptions(ix)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks a million in advance !

Please let me know if further info is needed

Answer (score 0):

In order to change data in list. You need to do this

```js
 const updateOptions = (ix: number) => {
    const newList = selectedOpt.map((m, i) => {
      if (i === ix) {
        return m + 1;
      }
      return m;
    });
    setSelectedOpts(newList);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks that works indeed ! would you know why it works compared to my solution ? Because it seems like mine update the props as well (cf. the check on props at onBtpress()).

Comment: I guess in your solution. Data wasn't updating.